# Complicated groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there a way to use the function form of `groupby()`, e.g. `groupby(f)` where f is a function, to group by table content? It looks like `f()` just gets called with the index.

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(age=30,sex='M',name='Jim',weight=143),
    dict(age=45,sex='F',name='Francine',weight=102),
    dict(age=22,sex='F',name='Jill',weight=190),
    dict(age=37,sex='M',name='Joseph',weight=221),
    dict(age=55,sex='M',name='Jerry',weight=187),
    dict(age=48,sex='M',name='Gus',weight=262),
    dict(age=45,sex='F',name='Jean',weight=112),
    dict(age=28,sex='F',name='Fiona',weight=133),
    dict(age=25,sex='M',name='Greg',weight=165),
    dict(age=34,sex='F',name='Jennifer',weight=137),
    dict(age=26,sex='M',name='Jason',weight=172),
    dict(age=28,sex='M',name='Jerome',weight=205),
    dict(age=61,sex='F',name='Faye',weight=140),
    dict(age=32,sex='M',name='Joshua',weight=180)])
df0.groupby('sex').mean()
```

This prints out

```
           age      weight
sex                       
F    39.166667  135.666667
M    35.125000  191.875000
```

but what if I want to group by sex and then by first letter of name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using str accessor with indexing as the second element in the groupby list:

```
df0.groupby(['sex',df0['name'].str[0]]).mean()
```

Output:

```
                age      weight
sex name                       
F   F     44.666667  125.000000
    J     33.666667  146.333333
M   G     36.500000  213.500000
    J     34.666667  184.666667
```

Comment: whoa, that's weird, so it just notices that I pass in a series that has the same index values?

Comment: What if my processing is more complicated than just a simple expression, so I need an external function?

Comment: Yes, I think the result must be the same length as the original dataframe.  There is an error you will get if the indexing or length doesn't match.

Comment: It must be matching it based on the index, because the answer remains unchanged even if you change the order and do `df0.groupby(['sex',df0.name.str[0].sort_values()]).mean()` but does get changed by `df0.groupby(['sex',df0.name.str[0].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)]).mean()`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use a function, you can create a new column:

```
def get_key(df):
    return df["sex"] + "-" + df["name"].str[0]

df0.assign(my_key=get_key).groupby("my_key").mean()
```